# intellij idea "Load error: undefined path variables" again and again

Tags: intellij-idea

after starting intellij idea I get everytime the message: "Load error: undefined path variables!". I click on fix it and a dialogwindow opens. I delete the path varaible, press apply and after that ok.

When I start idea again, the error is still there.

How can I fix this?

Thx.

Comment: What are the path variables that appear?

Comment: @CrazyCoder in my case, it's simple vars I defined like WORKBENCH for where I generally store my projects. Now I want to get rid of 'em and the IDE would prompt me everytime I open a project which was created with the vars defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some plugins require specific path variables. Deleting variable is not an option because plugin still needs it. F.E. Groovy plugin requires GROOVY_HOME variable. You have to specify value or switch corresponding plugin off.

Answer (score 7):

Had similar problem with PhpStorm 2016.
After using Xdebug, and adding some watch expressions, I couldn't get rid of the annoying warning until I edited the workspace.xml under .idea folder and removed the xml holding the "bad variable".

Comment: It was in "jarRepositories.xml" for me, but thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Bug still appears in current web storm versions. For me the solution was to edit JetBrains workspace file and remove breakpoints, there was one that was hidden there.
To fix, find the file located at: `<project folder>/.idea/workspace.xml`. and then find JSON element '`<component name="XDebuggerManager">`' and remove all breakpoints. element should now look as follows (the 3 dots for non-relevant parts to fix this bug):

```
...
    <breakpoint-manager>
          <breakpoints>
          </breakpoints>
          ...
          ...
    </breakpoint-manager>
...
```